# sequential countdown of array indexes with min/max numbers

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to get my application to get an array of random numbers, and use all possible combinations of rnd(1..8). The combinations are an array of indexes (length between 2-99). I've mimicked some test-code to show what I have so far, and included the results I'm looking for at the bottom.

To do this successfully, we want to look at function...

```
private static int[] updateArray(int[] array){
    for (int index = array.length - 1 ; index >= 0; index--){
        if (array[index] > 1){
            array[index]--;
            return array;
        } else if (array[index] == 1 && index != 0) {
            if (array[index - 1] != 1) {
                array[index - 1]--;
                array[index] = maxNum;
                return array;
            }
        }
        index--;
    }

    return array;
}
```

**Note:** I may not be using the correct algorithm above.

Here is the full code to compile results...

```
public class Test {
    private static final int maxNum = 8;

    private static int[] updateArray(int[] array){
        for (int index = array.length - 1 ; index >= 0; index--){
            if (array[index] > 1){
                array[index]--;
                return array;
            } else if (array[index] == 1 && index != 0) {
                if (array[index - 1] != 1) {
                    array[index - 1]--;
                    array[index] = maxNum;
                    return array;
                }
            }
            index--;
        }

        return array;
    }

    private static boolean isArrayIndexesAllOnes(int[] array){
        for (int element: array){
            if (element != 1){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static void printArrayCountdown(int[] array){
        boolean downToOne = false;

        while (!downToOne){
            array = updateArray(array);
            printArray(array);
            if (isArrayIndexesAllOnes(array)){
                downToOne = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void printArray(int[] array){
        for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++){

            if (index == 0) {
                System.out.print("{" + array[index] + ",");
            } else if (index > 0 && index < array.length - 1){
                System.out.print(array[index] + ",");
            } else {
                System.out.println(array[index] + "}");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] firstArray = {maxNum,maxNum};
        int[] secondArray = {maxNum,maxNum,maxNum};

        printArrayCountdown(firstArray);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        printArrayCountdown(secondArray);
    }
}
```

Expected Output of the `firstArray`...

```
{8,7}
{8,6}
{8,5}
{8,4}
{8,3}
{8,2}
{8,1}
{7,8}
{7,7}
{7,6}
{7,5}
{7,4}
{7,3}
{7,2}
{7,1}
{6,8}
{6,7}
{6,6}
{6,5}
{6,4}
{6,3}
{6,2}
{6,1}
{5,8}
{5,7}
{5,6}
{5,5}
{5,4}
{5,3}
{5,2}
{5,1}
{4,8}
{4,7}
{4,6}
{4,5}
{4,4}
{4,3}
{4,2}
{4,1}
{3,8}
{3,7}
{3,6}
{3,5}
{3,4}
{3,3}
{3,2}
{3,1}
{2,8}
{2,7}
{2,6}
{2,5}
{2,4}
{2,3}
{2,2}
{2,1}
{1,8}
{1,7}
{1,6}
{1,5}
{1,4}
{1,3}
{1,2}
{1,1}
```

**Success!**

But with an array of more than 2 indexes (e.g.: `secondArray`), I get this output:

```
{8,8,7}
{8,8,6}
{8,8,5}
{8,8,4}
{8,8,3}
{8,8,2}
{8,8,1}
{8,7,8}
{8,7,7}
{8,7,6}
{8,7,5}
{8,7,4}
{8,7,3}
{8,7,2}
{8,7,1}
{8,6,8}
{8,6,7}
{8,6,6}
{8,6,5}
{8,6,4}
{8,6,3}
{8,6,2}
{8,6,1}
{8,5,8}
{8,5,7}
{8,5,6}
{8,5,5}
{8,5,4}
{8,5,3}
{8,5,2}
{8,5,1}
{8,4,8}
{8,4,7}
{8,4,6}
{8,4,5}
{8,4,4}
{8,4,3}
{8,4,2}
{8,4,1}
{8,3,8}
{8,3,7}
{8,3,6}
{8,3,5}
{8,3,4}
{8,3,3}
{8,3,2}
{8,3,1}
{8,2,8}
{8,2,7}
{8,2,6}
{8,2,5}
{8,2,4}
{8,2,3}
{8,2,2}
{8,2,1}
{8,1,8}
{8,1,7}
{8,1,6}
{8,1,5}
{8,1,4}
{8,1,3}
{8,1,2}
{8,1,1}
{7,1,1}
{6,1,1}
{5,1,1}
{4,1,1}
{3,1,1}
{2,1,1}
{1,1,1}
```

**Logic Error!**

Instead, here is the **expected output**...

```
{8,8,7}
{8,8,6}
{8,8,5}
{8,8,4}
{8,8,3}
{8,8,2}
{8,8,1}
{8,7,8}
{8,7,7}
{8,7,6}
{8,7,5}
{8,7,4}
{8,7,3}
{8,7,2}
{8,7,1}
{8,6,8}
{8,6,7}
{8,6,6}
{8,6,5}
{8,6,4}
{8,6,3}
{8,6,2}
{8,6,1}
{8,5,8}
{8,5,7}
{8,5,6}
{8,5,5}
{8,5,4}
{8,5,3}
{8,5,2}
{8,5,1}
{8,4,8}
{8,4,7}
{8,4,6}
{8,4,5}
{8,4,4}
{8,4,3}
{8,4,2}
{8,4,1}
{8,3,8}
{8,3,7}
{8,3,6}
{8,3,5}
{8,3,4}
{8,3,3}
{8,3,2}
{8,3,1}
{8,2,8}
{8,2,7}
{8,2,6}
{8,2,5}
{8,2,4}
{8,2,3}
{8,2,2}
{8,2,1}
{8,1,8}
{8,1,7}
{8,1,6}
{8,1,5}
{8,1,4}
{8,1,3}
{8,1,2}
{8,1,1}
{7,8,8}
{7,8,7}
{7,8,6}
{7,8,5}
{7,8,4}
{7,8,3}
{7,8,2}
{7,8,1}
{7,7,8}
{7,7,7}
{7,7,6}
{7,7,5}
{7,7,4}
{7,7,3}
{7,7,2}
{7,7,1}
{7,6,8}
{7,6,7}
{7,6,6}
{7,6,5}
{7,6,4}
{7,6,3}
{7,6,2}
{7,6,1}
{7,5,8}
{7,5,7}
{7,5,6}
{7,5,5}
{7,5,4}
{7,5,3}
{7,5,2}
{7,5,1}
{7,4,8}
{7,4,7}
{7,4,6}
{7,4,5}
{7,4,4}
{7,4,3}
{7,4,2}
{7,4,1}
{7,3,8}
{7,3,7}
{7,3,6}
{7,3,5}
{7,3,4}
{7,3,3}
{7,3,2}
{7,3,1}
{7,2,8}
{7,2,7}
{7,2,6}
{7,2,5}
{7,2,4}
{7,2,3}
{7,2,2}
{7,2,1}
{7,1,8}
{7,1,7}
{7,1,6}
{7,1,5}
{7,1,4}
{7,1,3}
{7,1,2}
{7,1,1}
{6,8,8}
{6,8,7}
{6,8,6}
{6,8,5}
{ect...}
{1,1,1}
```

Any ideas how to get this kind of behavior?

**Note:** I don't want to actually print out `{ect...}`, for the purpose of not adding 512 lines on this question, I just cut out about 400 lines.

Thanks :)

Comment: Remove the `index--` inside your `updateArray` and it should fix the problem. No?

Comment: Close! but no, it's skipping between `{8,1,1} and {7,8,1}`... and `{7,1,1} and {6,8,1}`... so forth

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to thank anishthecoder response for really helping me narrow it down. Basically, I just had to remove the `index--` (as he said), and add an additional for loop. See code below...

```
private static int[] updateArray(int[] array){
    for (int index = array.length - 1 ; index >= 0; index--){
        if (array[index] > 1){
            array[index]--;
            return array;
        } else if (array[index] == 1 && index != 0) {
            if (array[index - 1] != 1) {
                array[index - 1]--;
                for (int i = index; i < array.length; i++){
                    array[i] = maxNum;
                }
                return array;
            }
        }
    }

    return array;
}
```

I'm sure there is a cleaner way to do this, and I would be happy to give the answer points to anyone who can come up with a cleaner solution. For now this is working...

Thanks again anishthecoder :)